# ASA 9.1 static PAT ("port forwarding") not working

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

The goal is to forward two different ports 1195 and 1196 from the outside address of the ASA to two different hosts on the inside but on the same port.

These are the addresses used in this example:

- ASA.Internet   192.168.1.99/24
- ASA.DMZ        172.16.0.1/24

Here is the relevant part of the config for one inside host:

```
object network VPN2
 host 172.16.0.66 
 nat (DMZ,Internet) static interface service udp 1194 1195

object service VPN
 service udp destination eq 1194

access-list Internet_access_in_1 extended permit object VPN any object VPN2
access-list Internet_access_in_1 extended deny ip any any
```

---

The questions are:

- **What is the correct way to use packet tracer in this case?**
- **What is the correct destination port to use in the ACL in this case?**

---

Experiments:

Using `packet-tracer input internet udp 8.8.8.8 1234 172.16.0.66 1194` (inside IP/port) I get

```
Phase: 7
Type: NAT
Subtype: rpf-check
Result: DROP
Config:
object network VPN2
 nat (DMZ,Internet) static interface service udp 1194 1195
Additional Information:
```

Using `packet-tracer input internet udp 8.8.8.8 1234 192.168.1.99 1195` (outside IP/port) I obviously get

```
Phase: 4
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype:
Result: DROP
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:
```

In any case, packets are currently hitting the firewall on the Internet(outside) interface on udp port 1195 but they aren't seen inside. `show nat detail`:

```
  (DMZ) to (Internet) source static VPN2 interface   service udp 1194 1195
     translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 0
     Source - Origin: 172.16.0.66/32, Translated: 192.168.1.99/24
     Service - Protocol: udp Real: 1194 Mapped: 1195
```

**Now what is making me crazy in addition**, if I add port 1195 to the access list, the following invocation of packet tracer accepts the traffic:

```
packet-tracer input internet tcp 8.8.8.8 1234 172.16.0.66 1195
```

That's the inside IP but the outside port? WT...?

Comment: I have to thank you big time for your post. I just spent two days scratching my head setting up a simple port forwarding. Can't believe Cisco made it so complicated.
Anyways I was having the same issue you mention, and solved it thanks to your post.
Cheers!
RVa.

Comment: No prob. The order of statements seems to be very important (and if using static nat also if you make it bidirectional or not). This is more or less trial and error though. Also ASDM sometimes shows weird things. I guess I will take  a course about NAT on the ASA next year. This is just too crazy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a manual Dynamic PAT (Hide) to any in NAT section 1. I moved it to after-auto (section 3) and all is good...

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.